# Submit DATE to a database if the user has unchecked check box & if the user has checked the current date will be submitted

Tags: php, mysql

I want to submit DATE to a database if the user has unchecked check box & selected date manually  & if the user has checked the checkbox the current date will be submitted to a database.
Check screenshot for better understanding [checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgNxu.png) [unchecked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TjdX.png)

form :

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Camp">Start Campaign Immediately: </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="Camp" onclick="onCheck(this);">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="campError"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="sel1">Campaign Start Date:</label>
    <input type="date" name="date" value="EnrollDate" id="date" onchange="checkDate(this);">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="dateError"></div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" id="btnEnter" name="b1" value="b1" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div
```

script :

```
    <script>
function onCheck(checkbox) {
    var dateElement = document.getElementById('date');
    dateElement.disabled = checkbox.checked;
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      //dateElement.value = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10);
      dateElement.valueAsDate = new Date();
    }
    else
      dateElement.value = '';
  }
  
var listA = [{name:'White', value:'White'}, {name:'Red', value:'Red'}, {name:'Black', value:'Black'}, {name:'Grey', value:'Grey'}];

var listB = [{name:'White', value:'White'}, {name:'Black', value:'Black'}];

$(document).ready( function() {
  $("input[name='chk']").on('click',function() {

      if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == '1')
      {
        $('#describ').empty()
        $.each(listA, function(index, value) {
         $('#describ').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
        });                  
      }
      else if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == '2')
      {
        $('#describ').empty()
        $.each(listB, function(index, value) {
         $('#describ').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
        }); 
      }
      else
      {

      }

  });
});  

</script>
```

insert.php :

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST["b1"]))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$chk = $_POST['chk'];
$describ = $_POST['describ'];
$Camp = $_POST['Camp'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
}

if ((!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($title) && !empty($chk) && !empty($chk) && !empty($describ) && !empty($Camp) && !empty($date)))
  {
 $host = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbname = "form";
    //create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
     die('Connect Error('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
     $SELECT = "SELECT email From form Where email = ? Limit 100";
     $INSERT = "INSERT Into form (name, email, title, chk, describ, Camp, date) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
     //Prepare statement
     $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->bind_result($email);
     $stmt->store_result();
     $stmt->store_result();
     $stmt->fetch();
     $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;
     
     if ($rnum==0) {
      $stmt->close();
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
      $stmt->bind_param("ssssssi", $name, $email, $title, $chk, $describ, $Camp, $date);
      $stmt->execute();
      echo "New record inserted sucessfully";
      } else {
      echo "Someone already register using this email";
      }
     $stmt->close();
     $conn->close();
    }
} else {
 echo "All field are required";
 die();
}
?>
```

The problem is date and checkbox value not getting inserted to the database. I'm using localhost/phpmyadmin/

Comment: Why exactly does this have the tag `laravel` in it? I dont see any laravel related code.

Comment: @RobBiermann Sorry! But if its possible for you to solve then please post your answer!